# Api call flutter

Tags: flutter, api, time

[image]

```
children: [
                Text('${cPrayerName} at  ${cPrayerTime}'),
                 Text('Remining time : $remingTime!)'
    ]
```

I put my cPrayerName and cPrayerTime and remingTime in a flip widget. at the start of the app, those variables empty the I execute a function that fetch data from API and add that reposne to a list  `List<PrayerTimeClass> prayerTime = [];` then I check my condition then assign it to those variables  `String cPrayerName = ""; , var cPrayerTime = "";` but it takes some time to see on flip widget i want to get rid of i need imiditate results

```
Future fetchPrayerTimeNExDay() async {

    var time = DateTime.now();
    setState(() {
      nextDayDate = "$year-$month-$day";
    });

   
    Response response =
        await dio.get("http://52.90.175.175/api/prayer-time/get/$currentDate");

    if (response.data["data"] != null) {
      prayerTimeNexDay.add(PrayerTimeClass.fromJson(response.data["data"]));
    }
```

This is condition i check

```
Dio dio = Dio();
  static List<PrayerTimeClass> prayerTime = [];



 


 Future fetchPrayerTime() async {
    String year = DateTime.now().year.toString();
    String month = DateTime.now().month.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    String day = DateTime.now().day.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    var time = DateTime.now();
    setState(() {
      currentDate = "$year-$month-$day";
    });

Response response =
    await dio.get("http://localhost/api/prayer-time/get/$currentDate");

if (response.data["data"] != null) {
  prayerTime.add(PrayerTimeClass.fromJson(response.data["data"]));

  DateTime fajirTime = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(
      "${DateTime.now().toString().substring(0, 10)} ${prayerTime[0].fajir}");
  DateTime dhuhrTime = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(
      "${DateTime.now().toString().substring(0, 10)} ${prayerTime[0].dhuhar}");
  DateTime asrTime = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(
      "${DateTime.now().toString().substring(0, 10)} ${prayerTime[0].asr}");
  DateTime magribTime = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(
      "${DateTime.now().toString().substring(0, 10)} ${prayerTime[0].magrib}");
  DateTime ishaTime = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(
      "${DateTime.now().toString().substring(0, 10)} ${prayerTime[0].isha}");
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  DateTime nextDayFajirTime = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(
      "${DateTime.now().toString().substring(0, 10)} ${prayerTimeNexDay[0].fajir}");

  if (now.isBefore(fajirTime)) {
    setState(() {
      cPrayerName = "Fajr";
      cPrayerTime = DateFormat.Hms().format(fajirTime);
      remingTime = fajirTime.difference(now);
    });
  } else if (now.isAfter(fajirTime) && now.isBefore(dhuhrTime)) {
    setState(() {
      cPrayerName = "Duhur";
      cPrayerTime = DateFormat.Hms().format(dhuhrTime);
      remingTime = dhuhrTime.difference(now);
    });
  } else if (now.isAfter(dhuhrTime) && now.isBefore(asrTime)) {
    setState(() {
      cPrayerName = "Asr";
      cPrayerTime = DateFormat.Hms().format(asrTime);
      remingTime = asrTime.difference(now);
    });
  } else if (now.isAfter(asrTime) && now.isBefore(magribTime)) {
    setState(() {
      cPrayerName = "Magrib";
      cPrayerTime = DateFormat.Hms().format(magribTime);
      remingTime = magribTime.difference(now);
    });
  } else if (now.isAfter(magribTime) && now.isBefore(ishaTime)) {
    setState(() {
      cPrayerName = "Isha";
      cPrayerTime = DateFormat.Hms().format(ishaTime);
      remingTime = ishaTime.difference(now);
    });
  } else {
    setState(() {
      cPrayerName = "Prayer";
      cPrayerTime = "Fajr";
      remingTime = fajirTime.difference(now);
    });
  }
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: this is predefined prayer time for a day and I get the prayer time from this response and and send the response to list and and check some condition and if true set the list value to  cPrayerName = "Fajr";
      cPrayerTime = DateFormat.Hms().format(fajirTime);
      remingTime = fajirTime.difference(now); so I want this function should only done in only once when app satrt

Comment: Please let me know if the answer helps you or you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

Call your API in your `init` method and instead of using `FutureBuilder`, use only the `Builder` if needed or even you don't need it at all if you're saving data into a list.

**Note:** You shouldn't call async method directly into the init method. Instead put it into another method/function that is not async or returning anything.

Here's an example how it'll be done:

```
  getPrayerTime(){
    Future fetchPrayerTimeNExDay() async {
      //api logic
    }
  }
  getPrayerTimeNextDay(){
    Future fetchPrayerTime() async {
      //api logic
    }
  }
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getPrayerTime();
    getPrayerTimeNextDay();
  }
```

and here's how Builder widget Looks like:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      body: Builder(
      builder: (context){
        return Container();
    },
       ),
      )
     );
  }
```

Comment: when i wrap my async method with another method prayerTime.add(PrayerTimeClass.fromJson(response.data["data"])); is not executing it does not add to list

Comment: It should add if you didn't made any mistake. try to call a setState and see if it updates or not.

Comment: i treid it does not work

Comment: Please share the code or make it reproduce-able.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/K8R7VN this is my fully working code

Comment: name of libraries you're using plus other classes used like PrayerTimeClass ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251685/discussion-between-tahir-and-afthal-ad).